# How to build Wcf service that runs/processes request after client that published task is closed?

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I am trying to build a WCF based web service hosted on IIS 7.0. WCF Service is hosted on IIS and is designed to accept requests from multiple WCF clients(console applications). Each WCF client will give/publish a task to service hosted on WCF. After publishing task client terminates or shuts down.

After a while Client will query WCF Service for status of the task it published, service will return the status either completed or terminated etc... for the query request.

I'm new to the paradigm of WCF and webservices. Can someone help me with WCF concepts that can help me achieve this. samples are appreciated.

Thanks,
--Prasad

Comment: Can you please make your question more concrete? What is it exactly that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you're looking for a WCF Service that keeps running after the client closes the connection and then make a new connection to that same service at a later time.

From the service's point of view, that new connection is a new, different client - so you're sharing the same service with multiple clients.

You can achieve this with the `InstanceContextMode.Single` service behavior:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class EvalService : IEvalService { ...
```

See [The lifetime of an instance of a WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911322/the-lifetime-of-an-instance-of-a-wcf-service).

Comment: Thanks it worked. However i've a follow question. For the implementation class i had "[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]" but for interface i didn't add "[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required )]". When i tried to browse the service URI i got http 404.8 error. When i added "[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required )]" the error went away and things worked. Can you tell me what was happening at backend. In the hyperlink that  was shared there was no interface for the calculatorservice so i didn't the issue with the example.